# The procedure below(when i uncomment the commented parts) shows 'no data found'..?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Hi I'm trying the code the below logic..i need help..
When i run the following procedure i get all the sids along with the corresponding pid for a particular month. but when i uncomment the parts that i have commented here i get the month and year displayed and then a message saying 'no data found'. Where am i going wrong?

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE mas(V_MONTH NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,V_YEAR NUMBER DEFAULT NULL,V_AID VARCHAR2) AS

V_MID VARCHAR2(50);
V_SID VARCHAR2(50);
v_v_month number := nvl(V_MONTH,to_number(to_char(sysdate,'mm')));
v_v_year number := nvl(V_YEAR,to_number(to_char(sysdate,'yyyy')));
v_is_sub PM.IS_SUB%TYPE;
V_DIST_s NUMBER;
V_DIST_t NUMBER;


 cursor c1 
  is
    select distinct a.mid,
                      b.sid
    from     pmt a
             inner join smt b  
             on (a.mid = b.mid)
    where    a.AID = V_AID      
    AND A.AID = B.AID 
    AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM A.RDATE)= v_v_month AND 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM A.RDATE)= v_v_year
    order by mid;

BEGIN


dbms_output.put_line('month : ' || v_v_month);
dbms_output.put_line('year : ' || v_v_year);

/*
select IS_SUB into v_is_sub from program_master where pid = 'V_AID';

IF v_is_sub = 1 then

  select count(*) into V_DIST_S from (select distinct sid from smt where aid = 'v_aid');

  select count(*) into V_DIST_T from (select distinct sid from tm where aid = 'v_aid');

   if(V_DIST_S = V_DIST_T) then

*/
    for rec1 in c1

    loop

      dbms_output.put_line('MID : ' || rec1.MID);
      dbms_output.put_line('SID : ' || rec1.SID);

    end loop;

--  else

  --  dbms_output.put_line('count of sids do not match');

--end if;

--else

--dbms_output.put_line('No sids available for the mentioned pid.');


--end if;

END MAS;
```

Comment: btw, normally PL/SQL developers use `p_` for parameters and either `v_` or `l_` for local variables. That would also avoid names like `v_v_month` in your example.

Answer (score 1):

```
where pid = 'V_AID';
```

`V_AID` is a **variable**, however, you have enclosed it within **single-quotation marks**, which makes it a **string**. So, you are actually looking for the value `'V_AID'` and not the value of the variable.

Modify it to:

```
select IS_SUB into v_is_sub from program_master where pid = V_AID;
```

And do the same wherever you have enclosed the variable in single-quotation marks.